# Remapping vim key for switching panels in NERDtree

Tags: vim, vi, nerdtree

I have to edit code on a server through [shellinabox](https://github.com/shellinabox/shellinabox) (shell forwarding through HTTPS).

I added the [NERDtree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) plugin. My problem is that switching between panels in vim is done with `CTRL+w`. When using it in a browser tab, well... it closes my browser tab.

What should I add to my `.vimrc` to remap `CTRL+w` to `F9`?

EDIT: Although the proposed solutions work so far, I'm looking to have `F9` do `CTRL+w`, not to have `F9 + w`.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: `map <F9> <C-w>`. Didn't work.

Comment: Please see my answer. The second snippet of configuration does exactly what you want on my vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that the `<C-w>` combination was remapped somewhere in your config.
Try using

```
:noremap <F9> <C-w>
```

to deal with this remapping. This would prevent recursive substitution of the command and it would execute the default action of `<C-w>`.
If you want to skip typing the additional `w` then use:

```
:noremap <F9> <C-w><C-w>
```

For more info see here: http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html

Answer (score 0):

Try `map <F9> :<CR><C-W>` this change `Ctr-w + w` to `F9 + w`

Comment: Nice. Is there a way to just have `F9` rather than `F9 + w`?